# Combine different geometry types in single layer in MapServer- is it possible?

Tags: wms, geometry, mapserver, sql-server-spatial, ms4w

I'm trying to display features with different geometry types in single `LAYER`. MapServer version 7.0.1 (MS4W 3.1.4). The data source is `MS SQL` spatial database table with `geometry` column, containing `Point` and `Polygon` geometry type features (all with the same SRID).

Here is most significant lines from `LAYER` configuration:

```
LAYER
 NAME "stations"

 CONNECTIONTYPE PLUGIN
 PLUGIN "msplugin_mssql2008.dll"
 CONNECTION "Server=.\DB1;uid=***;pwd=***;Database=***;Integrated Security=True"
 DATA "Geom FROM [Stations] USING UNIQUE Id USING SRID=3785"

 TYPE polygon
 #TYPE point
 CLASS
 ...
 END
END
```

I can define two `CLASS` declarations with corresponding `EXPRESSION` to filter by geometry type in `.map` file but the `TYPE` declaration is still required, omitting it gives `loadLayer(): General error message. Layer type not set.` error.

Is it possible to do using `MapServer` or defining separate `LAYER`s for each geometry type is the only option ?

Comment: Most styles are connected to points/lines/polygons and for example if polygon data is set to TYPE LINESTRING then it is not possible to render polygon fill. Defining separate layers will certainly work with WMS but perhaps single layer could work in WFS service.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, MapServer was based on shapefiles, and thus still has the restriction that a single layer can draw only one geometry type.

If you want to draw both points and polygons, you need two layers.
(And you need to use queries to filter out the wrong geometries, because MapServer will happily draw the polygon nodes as points. Use something like [STDimension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stdimension-geometry-data-type).)

Answer (score 0):

In these situations, I make multiple layers with different names but belonging to the same group, like this:

```
LAYER
    NAME "line_layer"
    GROUP "layer1"
    ....
    ....
END


LAYER
        NAME "polygon_layer"
        GROUP "layer1"
        ....
        ....
END
```

I filter the PostGIS table with `ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_LineString'`